# If points of mobius transformation are given, then how to determine the mapping?

Tags: intuition, mobius-transformation

A Mobius transformation is a map $$f(x)=\frac{rx+s}{tx+u}$$ where $ru-st \neq 0$. Suppose we have $f(a)=c, f(b)=d, f(c)=a, f(d)=b$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. Then from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629276/how-prove-this-integral-equation-int-ab-frac1-sqrtfxdx-int-c), the answer given by Noam, the coefficients of the transformation are
$$r=ad-bc, s=bcd-acd+abd-abc, t=a-b+c-d, u=bd-ac$$

Question: How to obtain the coefficients? I used the information above and then solve for $r,s,t,u$, but eventually I end up in a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out, you need $u=-r$ since the transformation is self-inverse.
So you now have $$f(x)=\frac{rx+s}{tx-r}$$
Now let $$\frac sr=P, \frac tr=Q$$
Now you can use $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$ to solve simultaneously for $P$ and $Q$